# TCHAR pointer initialization

Tags: c++, c, string, pointers, tchar

I am trying to understand the following code:

```
const TCHAR * portName = "COM15";
```

I understand that a TCHAR is either a Char (in ANSI) or a wChar (in Unicode), basically a 1 byte or 2 byte container that represents something.

Now, if I declare a pointer to a const TCHAR called portName, portName is then a pointer. When I use the "=" sign, I am giving that pointer a value, and it seems irrational to me that "COM15" would be the address. I assume that line of code is giving me a pointer to the location of the beginning of the "COM15" string of characters, correct?

So what is actually happening in that line of code?

Is a string of characters ("COM15") being created and the "=" sign actually means that the location of the beginning of that string is being given to portName?

Comment: To get this literal correctly use the `_T()` macro please: `const TCHAR * portName = _T("COM15");`

Comment: The string "COM15"  is stored in a read-only location and that location's address is returned to your pointer.

Comment: Note that the code is incorrect. It should be either `const char*` or `TEXT("COM15")`. The current example will not compile as Unicode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"Is a string of characters ("COM15") being created and the "=" sign actually means that the location of the beginning of that string is being given to portName?"*

Yes, exactly. But other than it sounds from your question as you might have expected, this happens when the program is compiled, and not at run time. Also the `const` keyword prohibits changing that pointer at runtime later.

Comment: Makes sense. I'll check out the _T() you told me about now too. Ty for that.

Comment: The `const` keyword in this code snippet applies to the pointee, the pointed to data. The pointer can be reassigned at runtime. The syntax for an immutable pointer would be `TCHAR* const`. For symbolic constants its usually best to declare both the pointer and the data pointed to as immutable: `const TCHAR* const`.

Answer (score 1):

**This how C works:**

When you say `char * str1` in C, you are allocating a pointer in the memory. When you write `str1 = "Hello";`, you are creating a string literal in memory and making the pointer point to it.

When you create another string literal `"new string"` and assign it to `str1`, all you are doing is changing where the pointer points.